# How to atomically check if mutex is locked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic, condition-variable

Consider this:

```
// Somewhere
std::mutex mutex;
std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
std::condition_variable condition;

// Thread01
condition.wait(lock);

// Thread02
while (lock.owns_lock());
```

So I got a situation like this where the loop at `Thread02` never ends, regardless of the fact that `Thread01` is waiting for the condition.

This means that unlocking the lock at `std::condition_variable::wait` does not synchronize with checking if the lock is locked at `std::unique_lock::owns_lock`. [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) it is explicitly told that the `wait` *"Atomically unlocks lock..."* but [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/owns_lock) nothing is told about `owns_lock` of being atomic or being synchronised with the lock operations.

So the question is: how can I *atomically check* it the `wait` has *atomically unlocked the lock*?

### EDIT:

The desire is to know at `Thread02` if `Thread01` is waiting for the condition. That's why I've accepted the answer.

Comment: Standard C++ threads and mutexes are not designed to be fair, or prioritized. Also, I think you misunderstand " atomically". That means undividable - an operation which can't be half-done. `owns_lock` does only a single thing. The quote you truncated continues _"Atomically unlocks lock, blocks the current executing thread, and ..."_. It literally does three things, and those 3 things happen together.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I misread the sentence. I thought the word *"Atomically"* refers to the first element in that comma-separated list, not to the list itself. English is not my native language, but I assume it could be written better in order to prevent misreading. Thanks!

Comment: There is no good answer to this question. If you are asking about "is thread one waiting" then the answer you'll get back is stale _as soon as you get it_ - its no longer trustworthy. You probably want to paste your real code and we can help convert it to proper synchronisation primitives for the requirements in hand. Also look up TOCTOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can momentarily lock the lock and get the desired Thread02:

```
// Thread02
std::unique_lock{mutex};
// mutex isn’t locked
```

Comment: That's not checking, it's actually locking. It'll block if the mutex is already locked.

Comment: @rustyx Yes, but that solves the issue. I've edited the question regarding this.